# Appending a string to collectors.joining function in spring.io project

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring.io. I have the section of code below
where I am retrieving 1 or more email addresses. 
I want to be able to append `myEmailAddress` to the return `emailTargets.stream()` section

How can I do that ?

```
String myEmailAddress = solution.getCustomerEmail();

List<Employee> emailTargets = this.employeeRepository.search(EmployeeSearchCriteria.builder()
                .branchCode(customer.getBusinessUnitCode())
                .employeeId(solution.getModifiedBy())
                .role(Arrays.asList(Role.GOV))
                .build());

return emailTargets.stream()
                .map(Employee::getEmailAddress)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("," ));
```

Comment: return emailTargets.stream()
                  .map(Employee::getEmailAddress)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining("," )).concat("," + myEmailAddress);

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate the stream with one created on the fly:

```
return Stream.concat(emailTargets.stream().map(Employee::getEmailAddress), 
                     Stream.of(myEmailAddress))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```